# Selenium execute javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

In the javascript console for Chrome Browser, I executed, `document.querySelector('shop-app /deep/ shop-button')`, it returns the  tag.When I try to execute the same within selenium webdriver using selenium java driver(**v 53**) and the latest version of **ChromeDriver**, I get NullPointer,

```
WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('shop-app /deep/ shop-button')");
```

Iam trying to access the shop button on the web site,https://shop.polymer-project.org/.Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: there are 4 shop now button you wish to access all of them?

Comment: I am trying the access the first button, in the Men's Outerwear section.Slightly modified code is :WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('shop-app /deep/ shop-button')");
  WebElement mensOuterWearBtn = shadowRoot.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
  mensOuterWearBtn.click();

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to click on a shop button finding element using simple find elements. Below is one a snippet of code for that:

```
WebElment logoElement = findElement(By.className("logo")).findElement(By.tagName("a"));
logoElement.click();
```

You can also try this searching through Xpath:

```
WebElment logoElement = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="header"]/app-toolbar/div[2]"));
logoElement.click();
```